# SlicerCaches.SlicerItems(integer number) throwing runtime error 5

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, pivot-table, slicers

I am working on a model which includes a macro to update pivottables and select sliceritems. Included in this is a loop through the sliceritems which sets all of them to 'select = false', except for current year.

The code stops on the line below, and I cannot figure out why. I have spent way to much time trying to figure it out, so I need to ask your help..
*if ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Years").SlicerItems(i).Selected then*

- in this case, i has got the value of 2
- i is an integer value
- when I replace the i with a 2, it works and I get a *true* or *false*
- when I replace the 2 with i, I get runtime error 5

This is my code (there is more code below it, but this is what is relevant). It stops on the line 'If sCYears.SlicerItems(i).Selected Then' with Runtime error 5.

```
Sub RefreshPivots()

'Declare variables
    Dim tblPivot As PivotTable
    Dim strCYear, strMonth As String
    Dim sCYears, sCDate As SlicerCache
    Dim i As Integer
    
'Populate variables
    strCYear = "" & Sheets("Start").Range("Cyear").Value
    strMonth = Sheets("Lookup").Range("NorskPer").Value
    Set sCYears = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Years")
    Set sCDate = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date")

'Loop to refresh all pivottables
    For Each tblPivot In ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables
        tblPivot.RefreshTable
    Next tblPivot

'Set slicer for year
    For Each tblPivot In sCYears.PivotTables
        tblPivot.ManualUpdate = True 'Stops PivotTable from refreshing after each PivotItem is changed
    Next tblPivot`

    sCYears.SlicerItems(1).Selected = True 'at least one item must be selected
    For i = 2 To sCYears.SlicerItems.Count
        If sCYears.SlicerItems(i).Selected Then sCYears.SlicerItems(i).Selected = False 'de-select all other items
    Next i
    sCYears.SlicerItems(strCYear).Selected = True 'select current year
    If sCYears.SlicerItems(1).Name <> strCYear Then 'de-select item 1 if not current year
        sCYears.SlicerItems(1).Selected = False
    End If

end sub`
`
```

Comment: Check to make sure that you're using the correct slicer cache name.  Right-click your slicer, select Slicer Settings, and check to see if the name specified in `Name to use in formulas` matches the name specified in your code.

Comment: If you add `debug.print sCYears.SlicerItems(i).name` before `If sCYears.SlicerItems(i).Selected` ... is the debug.print gives you the expected result ? Another way, `sCYears.ClearManualFilter` ... then loop to each item in sCYears to check it's name `For i = 1 To sCYears.SlicerItems.Count` .... `With sCYears.SlicerItems(i)` ...  if the looped item name = strCYear then selected=true else selected = false... `If .Name = strCYear Then .Selected = True Else .Selected = False` ... `end with` ... `next i`

Comment: Hello Domenic and thanks for your advice and help. I can confirm that I am using the correct reference to the slicer. As stated, if I replace the variable 'i' with a number within the number of items in the slicer, I get the correct result. 

The same phenomena is true for the other .sliceritems functions such as '.name', so I can easily verify that the correct slicercache is in use.

This one is tricky.

Comment: Hello Karma and thank you very much for your input and help!

Your suggestions in order:                                
- The same phenomena is true for sCYears.SlicerItems(i).Name. It throws 'Run-Time error 5' but it works when I replace the 'i' with a number.               
- I tried the sCYears.ClearManualFilter and then added your loop, but I cannot get past the 'With sCYears.SlicerItems(i)' line. I get the same 'Run-time error 5'. This loop could also potentially remove all selections from slicer which will cause a fail.                  

What could possibly be causing this error?

Comment: Hello all,

If anyone stumbles upon this thread, I managed to find the solution by reducing the code to a bare minimum and re-building it. The line causing the error, even though I cannot understand how, was this line:       

'Dim sCYears, sCDate As SlicerCache'. When I split that up into two lines, the code works as expected, ie: Dim sCYears As SlicerCache / Dim sCDate As SlicerCache'. 

I hope that helped someone!
Best regards,
Ronnie